# Can you change the browser profile in Ruby WQatir / Selenium mid-stream?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I know that I can initially set   special profile by designating a myProfile and saying

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => myProfile
```

but is it possible to declare

```
browser = Watir:Browser.new :firefox
```

to start out my test with the standard profile and then switch to myProfile later?  What is the syntax to do that?

Comment: Yes,you can do it.But for that you have to create two different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define your scenario ? Because, I had done profile related things, but I had not need to change profile later. I had set profile at beginning of file just to tell Firefox not to appear it's download prompt dialog box, to just download file at told destination.

So, it will be interesting to know why you are trying to change profile later.

Comment: I need to sometimes display PDFs and sometimes save them directly to the HD without displaying them.

Comment: Yours a custom scenario, can not help with profile changing, but for your scenario you can use autoit, like to open file in firefox, you can use: `@ai = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control"); @ai.WinWaitActive("[REGEXPTITLE:Opening]"); sleep 3; @ai.Send("{ENTER}")`